# How can I hide or show all the divs came out from th:each by using jquery?

Tags: html, jquery, spring, spring-boot

First of all, I'm sorry for my bad English.

Recently I'm doing project using Spring Boot and
I'm struggling with hiding or showing all the divs created by th:each

```
<button class="category" onclick="showBar()">BAR</button>


<div id="barList" th:each="m: ${MERCH}" th:if="${m.cat.catId}==1">
<tr>
    <p th:text="${m.getMName()}"></p><br>
    <p th:text="${#numbers.formatInteger(m.price, 1, 'COMMA')}"></p>
</tr>
</div>


<script>
function showBar() {
    $('#barList').hide();
}
</script>
```

this is part of HTML that I'm struggling with

What I see on devtool in chrome is that first div seems to work(style="display : none;" is created) but other divs come out after doesn't work at all.

How can I hide or show all the divs came out from th:each... T.T

Even if it doesn't use JQuery, it doesn't matter. I just want to hide all.

Again sorry for my bad Enlgish.. Hope you understood..
Thanks!

Comment: I don't know much about spring-boot, but is the `<div id="barList">` getting created multiple times? or only the content inside.? If the div is created multiple times then you are getting multiple elements with the same id and that will not work.

Comment: It creates <div id="barList"> for multiple times. Then I see what's the problem... Thanks a lot.